# How to use p12 certificates in Android (client certificates)

Tags: android, security, https, client-certificates

I'm trying to use client certificates in android.
I got a .p12 file that i want to use to authenticate towards the server.

I am using portecle to convert the .p12 file to a .bks file but i don't seem to get it to work.

Here's the code:

```
package com.pa1406.SECURE;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;

import android.content.Context;

public class HttpsClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

  final Context context;

  public HttpsClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(
        new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(
        new Scheme("https",newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
  }

  private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
      KeyStore truststore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");

      InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);

      try {
          truststore.load(in, "qwerty1234".toCharArray());
      } finally {
        in.close();
      }
      return new SSLSocketFactory(truststore);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }

  }
}
```

What can i do to accomplish this?

UPDATE:

```
package com.pa1406.SECURE;


import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;

import android.content.Context;

public class HttpsClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

  final Context context;

  public HttpsClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(
        new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(
        new Scheme("https",newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
  }

  private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
        // setup truststore to provide trust for the server certificate

        // load truststore certificate
        InputStream clientTruststoreIs = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.truststore);
        KeyStore trustStore = null;
        trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        trustStore.load(clientTruststoreIs, "qwerty1234".toCharArray());

        System.out.println("Loaded server certificates: " + trustStore.size());

        // initialize trust manager factory with the read truststore
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = null;
        trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        // setup client certificate

        // load client certificate
        InputStream keyStoreStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.torbix);
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, "qwerty1234".toCharArray());

        System.out.println("Loaded client certificates: " + keyStore.size());

        // initialize key manager factory with the read client certificate
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = null;
        keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "qwerty1234".toCharArray());

     // initialize SSLSocketFactory to use the certificates
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = null;
        socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.TLS, keyStore, "qwerty1234",
            trustStore, null, null);

      return socketFactory;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point where you have to change your code is when your new SSLSocketFactory instance:

```
return new SSLSocketFactory(truststore);
```

The SSLSocketFactory class has other constructors, one of them allows to specify a keystore, the keystore password and a truststure:

`public SSLSocketFactory (KeyStore keystore, String keystorePassword, KeyStore truststore)`([JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#SSLSocketFactory%28java.security.KeyStore,%20java.lang.String,%20java.security.KeyStore%29))

I am not sure if you can load your `.P12` file under Android as KeyStore (on J2SE you can). If you can not you have to convert the `.P12` file to a Bouncy castle keystore similar to the truststore you are already using. Use that key store to create your SSLSocketFactory instance and you should be able to use the client certificate.

**Importing a P12 file into BKS via Portecle**

Creating a `BKS` file and importing existing `.key`+`.pem` file is very simple using [Portecle GUI](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) (Java program). After starting Portecle select *File -> New Keystore -> BKS*. Afterwards you can execute *Tools -> Import Key Pair* and select the `.P12` file. 
Finally save the key store protected with a password of your choice.

Comment: I tried to use the .p12 file but it didn't work, need to convert it. I'm not sure if i'm doing right. I'll update the question so you can se were i am now.

Comment: For converting P12->BKS I would use the tool [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net) - if you prefer a GUI instead of a command-line.

Comment: That's what i am using, how do i do to convert it? Do i open .p12 with portecle and export the key and the certificate and then add them to my new keystore or should i do something else? :)

Comment: I'm also struggling to find out how to convert a P12 -> BKS in Portecle, any ideas?