# Android: Authenicating with certificates for Exchange Server using HTTP Methods

Tags: android, http-post, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, android-keystore

I am trying to sync with my exchange server using HTTP Methods(HttpPost) with the client certificate (abc.pfx) which is generated by the server. I tried using KeyStore, KeyManagerFactory,TrustManagerFactory and SSLSocketFactory to acheive this. But iam getting

1. Authentication Error (If i trust all certificates) Received authentication challenge is null
2. java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. (If i trust only the server (Root CA) cert).

I had gone through many Links in StackOverflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064810/using-client-server-certificates-for-two-way-authentication-ssl-socket-on-androi),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311295/how-to-use-p12-certificates-in-android-client-certificates),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714993/https-connection-with-client-certificate-in-an-android-app),[4](http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html). If u can see all the links are atmost same. I tried different ways but still no use.

Note: I am using abc.pfx (it is not self signed), server.cer (to make this trust). Iam converting both file into BKS format and using in my code. Plz help me to solve this problem